# Checking if Mongodb field already exists within a document in database

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas

Would I put the code to find a document with an existing field in the server.js. Or could I do this in the front end (reactjs) because I have a counter field that I'd like to increment if it is trying to be added but the field already exists.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!\n'))
.catch(err => {
console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', () =>{
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
})
const trackRouter = require('./routes/track');

app.use('/track', trackRouter);

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('Server is running on port: 5000');
})
```

And heres my track.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const trackSchema = new Schema({
    track:{type:String, required: true},
    trackID:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    year:{type:Number, required:true},
    genre:{type:String, required:true},
    album:{type:String,required:true},
    artist:{type:String, required:true},
    artistID:{type:String, required:true},
    count:{type:Number, required:true},

}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const Track = mongoose.model('Track', trackSchema);

module.exports = Track;
```

Lastly here is the track.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Track = require('../models/track.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    Track.find()
        .then(track => res.json(track))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const track = req.body.track;
    const trackID = req.body.trackID;
    const year = Number(req.body.year);
    const genre = req.body.genre;
    const artist = req.body.artist;
    const artistID = req.body.artistID;
    const album = req.body.album;
    const count = Number(req.body.count);


    const newTrack = new Track({
        track,
        trackID,
        year,
        genre,
        album,
        artist,
        artistID,   
        count,
    });
    newTrack.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Song added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
router.route('/:id').get((req,res) => {
    Track.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(exercise => res.json(exercise))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
}); 
router.route('/:id').delete((req,res) => {
    Track.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(() => res.json('Song deleted'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
router.route('/update/:id').post((req,res) => {
    Track.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(track=>{
        track.track = req.body.track;
        track.trackID = req.body.trackID;
        track.year = Number(req.body.year);
        track.genre = req.body.genre;
        track.album = req.body.album;
        track.artist = req.body.artist;
        track.artistID = req.body.artistID;
        track.count = req.body.count;
        track.save()
            .then(() => res.json('Song updated!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: '+ err));
})

module.exports = router;
```

The front end (reactJS) inserting document inside database

```
 const playlist1 = {
            track: tracks[currentTrack].name,
            trackID:tracks[currentTrack].id,
            year:parseInt(this.state.year),
            genre:this.state.genre,
            album: tracks[currentTrack].album.name,
            artist: tracks[currentTrack].artists[0].name,
            artistID: tracks[currentTrack].artists[0].id,
            count: 1,
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/track/add', playlist1)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Mongo shell, you can [write a query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to see if a given field exists.

`db.collection.find({field: {$exists: true}})`

Without being able to see your code or the context, I can't be positive what writing that query will look like for you.

Typically, you would put that query in the server and expose an API route to your UI so that it can access the information returned by the query in whatever format you prefer.

***UPDATE***

After receiving your updated comments, I see that you are not wanting to see if the *field* exists, but rather that a specific value exists in a field.

That can be accomplished with an update query where you specify the `trackID` in the query and increment the counter in the update object.

```js
const trackID = 1
await Track.findOneAndUpdate(
   { trackID },              // The query to find the docs to update
   { $inc: { count: 1 } },   // The actual update to perform
   { upsert: true },         // Mongoose options. This one will create the document if it doesn't exist
)
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: yeah I need to write the code somewhere, not in the shell. I want to increment a counter field if the trackID (unique) already exists in a document in the database. So id make a conditional like: if(trackID field exists){$inc{counter:1}} else{insert new document}

Comment: posted my server.js along with the crud operation code and the model of each track

Comment: That query still works with Mongoose as well. Will update to show what I mean.